# How do web apps create subdomains?

Tags: web-development, web-applications

I want to understand the architecture of web apps that use subdomains. I don't think that I'm phrasing this well, so let me explain.

Many web apps, like tumblr or shopify create a user's site on a subdomain. Say for example my tumblr account was `johndoe` then you could find my tumblr blog at `johndoe.tumblr.com`. Can someone explain how this is implemented?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically you could either set new CNAME record to your DNS server for each user (if you have such ability by your Hosting/DNS server provider) or use the [Wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) method and then use some rewrite rules to process the requests.

You can read more about it on [this older post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user).

Comment: Ahh, thank you! This is an awesome start. And the added vocabulary - wildcard subdomains - makes this a much easier topic to Google!

Answer (score 3):

If you could't edit your DNS record, you can also insert a subdomain which will be pointing to `*.yourdomain.com` and it willl receive any subdomains, that way you will can check on your system if that subdomain inserted by the user is a valid domain, check on a whitelist array, os simply checking on the database if the user exists on the system.

Comment: That's the Wildcard DNS record method i mentioned earlier.